# YTD Average of Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

Can anyone help me in creating a YTD Average % Calculation?

I have created 'A','B' by using the following DAX

A = DIVIDE([Current Month W/Allowance Over 90 $],[Aging],0)

B = DIVIDE([UnderBill],[OverBill],0)

Now I need to create a YTD Average % calculation based on the above two calculations.

This is what I am looking for

YTD A = Average of 'A' ( This average should be YTD)

YTD B = Average of 'B' ( This average should be YTD)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdnIV.png)

So if we look at YTD A for 08/01/2019, in excel I did the Average =AVERAGE(C2:C9) and the result is 65% and for next month it should be =AVERAGE(C2:C10) and the result is 61%

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a `Calendar` table which has `Calendar[Year]` and `Calendar[YearMonth]` columns, here is a possible solution.

```
YTD A = 

-- Calculated table which has start and end dates of each YTD months
VAR YearMonthsYTD =
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER( 
            ALL( 'Calendar' ),
            'Calendar'[Year] = MAX( 'Calendar'[Year] )
                && 'Calendar'[Date] <= MAX( 'Calendar'[Date] )
        ),
        'Calendar'[YearMonth]
    ),
    "@StartDate", CALCULATE( MIN( 'Calendar'[Date] ) ),
    "@EndDate", CALCULATE( MAX( [Date] ) )
)

-- Calculate the value for each month, and get the average of them
RETURN
AVERAGEX(
    YearMonthsYTD,
    CALCULATE(
        [A],
        FILTER(
            ALL( 'Calendar' ),
            'Calendar'[Date] >= [@StartDate] && 'Calendar'[Date] <= [@EndDate]
        )
    )
)
```

---

BTW, although I'm ignorant in accounting, I'm doubting if your calculation logic is correct, because *average of percentages* will not be an appropriate measure in general.

In the presented scenario, wouldn't this definition be more appropriate?

```
YTD A = DIVIDE( <YTD value of numerator>, <YTD value of denominator> )
```

This is not only to make it correct, but also to make it much easier.

```
YTD A = CALCULATE( [A], DATESYTD( 'Calendar'[Date] ) )
```

Forgive and forget if this is not a relevant comment for the specific case of OP.

Comment: Even I used the same logic in the beginning but this business is not looking at YTD calculation as YTD A = DIVIDE( <YTD value of numerator>, <YTD value of denominator> )..............They are looking at "A" calculation which is the % of each month and doing the Average of that. Since I have Slicer for Date and Region then I Average of "A" should also work If I am slicing and dicing by region and dates.